# Is it possible to create two Gmail web-apps for two Gmail accounts?

Tags: webapps, gmail

I am on Ubuntu Quantal, freshly installed. I have one personal Gmail account and another professional Google apps account.

I have managed to integrate my personal Gmail account to the Gmail webapp, but the application is quite useless to me if I can't plug the second account too.

Is it possible to create two webapps, one for each account?

Comment: I know Firefox and Chromium are supported. You might try one account per browser as a workaround. Not sure if Chromium = Chrome for webapps though. This is disappointing news, I haven't switched to 12.10 yet and just assumed this was possible.

Comment: @TomBrossman yes, both browsers are supported, but clicking on the app icon directly opens the default browser, so that's not possible... And Chromium != Chrome for webapps, I had to uninstall chrome and install chromium instead for the apps to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have 2 sepparate Web Apps for 2 accounts. They are just shortcuts that provide unity integration.

However, you can be logged in to 2 or more e-mail accounts on one gmail account. You just need to click on your profile image in Gmail and select "add account" (or something like that). That's a quite simple solution. Though, I'm not sure it will privide the same Web App integration as I'm not using this feature at the moment.

Comment: yes, that might be the right answer unfortunately. I was hoping maybe some text file editing could do the trick, but couldn't find any documentation on the subject so far.

Answer (score 0):

The webapps simply load a browser session.  If it is possible to have two gmail accounts open in the same browser, then it is possible to have two webapps for two different accounts.  I don't think it is, though.

You may want to have a look at Evolution or Thunderbird to handle your email, instead.

Comment: I don't use/know webapps, but you can create multiple firefox profiles with different google accounts, `firefox -P -no-remote` then `firefox -P <PROFILE_NAME> -no-remote`.

Comment: it is possible, but it is only possible to assign one account per webapp... I have tried using evolution a while ago, but imap is too slow compared to the web interface

Comment: @user55822 I can open my two accounts under the same firefox/chrome profile using multiple sign in, no problem here. Having one webapp for each would enable one dashboard link to each separate account.